# What is the font used in the new logo of themeforest?

Tags: fonts

Could someone tell me what font used in the logo Themeforest?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken it is [Dosis](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Dosis)

[image]

Comment: It may be based on Dosis, but if so, it’s definitely had some extra work done to it (it’s wider than Dosis, the e’s are quite different, and the f is quite different, too).

Comment: Agreed, you can definitely see the kerning in the logo is smaller as well.